# django: passing data via ajax to views, and then into forms for cleaning

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, forms

Ok, here's what I understand so far:
I can pass data from jquery to django as a json format as such:
AJAX Data: {'name' : 'flag', list_of_ids : [12,32,12,32]}

Django's request.POST data: {'name' : 'flag', 'list_of_ids[]' : [12,32,12,32]}

now, to access the list in django, you'd do this: request.POST.getlist('list_of_ids')

Now, suppose i want to clean that input of list_of_ids[].

SO I create a forms.py with name = forms.CharField(), and list_of_ids = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ObjectModel.objects.all(), required=False)

the returned "cleaned" data happens to be: {'name' : 'flag', 'list_of_ids' : []}

Now my question is, how can I make forms.py work with this such that it actually takes in list_of_ids[], and outputs a cleaned_data of list_of_ids?
Is this possible to do?

**EDIT**
Here's my class form:

```
class ModelForm(form.Form):
    name = form.CharField()
    relation = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ForeignObjects.objects.all(), required=False)
```

And then here's views.py atm:

```
def test_view(request):
    form = ModelForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        #do stuff
    #do stuff
```

and here's the ajax call:
    
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test_url/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                name : 'test',
                list_of_ids: [12,32,41]
            }
        })

Ok, as explained, from javascript to django, it will be this kind of data:

```
{
    'name' : 'test',
    'list_of_ids[]' : [12,32,41]
}
```

this is what django sees. so accessing list_of_ids[] would be request.POST.getlist('list_of_ids[]').
Now, if I pass this to the form, django does not catch list_of_ids[] but instead maps list_of_ids as an empty list. How do I catch this in forms? would it need to be a list of objects? (I've tried this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uh, this is really dumb, but the solution is basically this:

```
$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

Add that piece of code in the javascript PRIOR to calling your post request.
What this does is it goes back to vanilla flavor jquery where a list_of_ids[] goes back to just being list_of_ids, and from there, passing request.POST in the form cleans the data as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already use 'form', then what I did is:
views.py:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    ***do something ***
else:
    form = MyForm()  # this is an empty form
return render(request, 'my**.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: no, that's not what I need.
so in our code above, what if you pass from jquery to django this:
list_of_ids = [1,2,3,4]

in django, it'll show up as this:
request.POST:
'list_of_ids[]' : [1,2,3,4]

now, I want to clean that by passing that on to the form

however, it doesn't recognize list_of_ids[] as list_of_ids but instead returns list_of_ids: [], an empty list

so my question is how do I clean that list of ids?

Comment: if your familiar with pdb: 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()' before 'if form.is_valid()' to check whether you have got cleaned_data. It seems your form is not valid.

Comment: it is cleaned, it just drops the list_of_ids[] since it doesn't recognize that i'm trying to refer to list_of_ids

regardless, I want to catch an array of integers from a json object and pass it to forms such that it cleans it for me

Comment: I am wondering maybe there are some type error, or why it drops the list_of_ids. Also, is it list_of_ids, or list_of_ids[] ?

Comment: from jquery to django, the data are as follows:
{
  name : ______,
  list_of_ids[] : [ __,__,__,__],
}

Django receives them as 'name', and 'list_of_ids[]'